# Custom width of Vaadin GridLayout

Tags: alignment, vaadin, grid-layout, vaadin7

I'm working with a 2x2 GridLayout in Vaadin.

```
    gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        gridLayout.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        gridLayout.setMargin(true);
        gridLayout.setSpacing(true);
```

The cell in the upper-left corner contains a simple label aligned to the right. Upper-right cell contains a textfield aligned to the left. The second row simply contains a label below the textfield.

```
    gridLayout.addComponent(captionLabel, 0, 0);
    gridLayout.addComponent(inputField, 1, 0);

    gridLayout.setComponentAlignment(captionLabel, Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT);
    gridLayout.setComponentAlignment(inputField, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
```

Now I want to have both columns within the grid to have size set to 50% to have the whole layout aligned in the middle of my page - now it is slightly shifted to the left side and I can not figure out why...

Vaadin's wiki-page shows a related article, but I can not figure out how to work with it. Seems to be deprecated, because I can not access #getColumn(); - method?! https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/10674/Configuring+Grid+column+widths

For further info: The GridLayout is added as a separate component to a VerticalLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a HorizontalLayout-wrapper for the left column containing the label. The right colum contains a VerticalLayout with all other components.

```
    Label captionLabel = new Label(localized);
    captionLabel.setSizeUndefined();
    HorizontalLayout wrapper = new HorizontalLayout();
    wrapper.setSizeFull();
    wrapper.addComponent(captionLabel);
    wrapper.setComponentAlignment(captionLabel, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
    [...]        
    gridLayout.addComponent(wrapper, 0, 0);
    gridLayout.addComponent(inputLayout, 1, 0);
    gridLayout.setColumnExpandRatio(0, (float)0.5);
    gridLayout.setColumnExpandRatio(1, (float)0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can influence the column width's with the `grid.setColumnExpandRatio(1, 1);` method.

If you wish to have both use 50% of the total width, just set the expand ration to the same value on both columns.

Please also note this:
A layout that contains components with percentual size must have a defined size!

**If a layout has undefined size and a contained component has, say, 100% size, the component would fill the space given by the layout, while the layout would shrink to fit the space taken by the component, which is a paradox. This requirement holds for height and width separately.**

[Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( grid.setColumnExpandRatio(1, 1); does not affect the appearance of my layout. What I do not understand: I have the same composition except with a ComboBox instead of the textfield. But this component is slightly shifted to the right sight of the layout...

Comment: Can you add a printscreen of the layout you receive and what you expect?